# Facebook API, getting pages user admins (manage_pages)

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm making a web based Facebook APP using the PHP SDK.

I'm trying to get a list of all the pages, the user admins, and display them to the user.

This is currently not working, even though I'm testing it all in a test app, where you don't need to get the extended permission reviewed and accepted.

```
if (isset($session)) {
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,accounts'  );
    $response = $request->execute();
    //get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    $name = $graphObject->getProperty('name');
    $id = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
    $email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');
    $accounts = $graphObject->getProperty('accounts');

    echo "Your name is: ";
    echo "$name.";
    echo "<br>$accounts";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's odd but I didn't find method FacebookRequest->execute()...
However I found a solution which works for me:

```
function GetPages()
{
    $token = 'CurrentUsersTokenIsHere';
    // Instantiates a new Facebook super-class object from SDK Facebook\Facebook
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id'     => $fb_app_id,
        'app_secret' => $fb_app_secret
    ]);
    $response = $fb->get(
        '/me?fields=accounts,name,email',
        $token
    );
    $graphObject = $response->getDecodedBody();
    $fbUserName  = $graphObject['name'];
    $fbUserEmail = $graphObject['email'];
    $fbUserID    = $graphObject['id'];
    $pages       = $graphObject['accounts'];
    // In general there is an array and you can get each page like:
    $singlePage  = $pages['data']['0'];
    $pageName    = $singlePage['name'];
    $pageCategory= $singlePage['category'];
    $pageID = $singlePage['id'];
    return $pages;
}
```

One more thing, let's say for understanding, **$graphObject['accounts']** it's an array which looks like:

```
array(
'data' => array (
        0 => array (
                  'access_token' => 'someToken',
                  'category'     => 'Some category',
                  'name'         => 'Some name',
                  'id'           => 'Some id',
                  'perms'        => array (
                                          0 => 'CREATE_ADS',
                                          1 => 'BASIC_ADMIN',
                                    ),
                 ),
        1 => ...
        ),
'paging' => array (
        'cursors' =>array (
                    'before' => 'Mzc4MDAwOTcyMjE4MTYw',
                    'after' => 'MTQ1MTM2NzgxNTE0MDkwMAZDZD',
                    ),
                  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have the `manage_pages` permission
2. try the same call with the same access token in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me), if it's not there then it's not a PHP SDK issue
3. try to debug `$response` and see what's in it

Answer (score 0):

First of all `<page_id>/admins` end point is deprecated in version v2.2 and higher [check it here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/admins) But if you have [v2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/admins) you can do

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '<your_page_id>/admins'  );
$response = $request->execute();
// Todo with $response
```

**Note: Make sure you are sending this request along with Page Access Token.**